# Chrome not displaying Class set by jQuery or a Direct CSS property

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

This might seem like a bit of a design/css question but i really need some help.

This is the page http://library.permilia.com/Gavin/version2.0_beta/lead.html

It works on every browsers imaginable except chrome.

By it works i mean it applies a class .error that sets the borders to 1px solid #f00 which is a red border. In chrome for some reason you cannot change it no matter what!

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So..., the answer is that none of your JS code is ever firing, because Chrome is implementing HTML5 input elements, including form validation. So, unless you correctly fill in the fields, your *validation* code will never fire!

In HTML5 the `required` attribute is a boolean, its either true or false. According to [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#statically-validate-the-constraints), the browser should fire an `invalid` event on the problem field. You can cancel the default blocking behavior at that point if you want. However, your script breaks down again where you try `attr('required')`. It will return `true` or `false` in Chrome, using HTML5, not a value like `email` as you expect.

So you need to add these two pieces if you want this to work:

```
$(":input").bind("invalid", function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // Don't block the form submit
});
```

And then re-factor your code from

```
var a = $(this).attr('required');
```

to be

```
var a = $(this).attr('required') ? $(this).attr('type') : "";
```

And change your switch statement to match if needed

**One last idea**: You could also take a really cool approach (aka Feature Detection), and do this instead:

Wrap the inside of your current `validate:` function with this:

```
if(typeof $('<input />')[0].checkValidity === "undefined") {
  ... existing code ..
} else {
  $(':input').bind('invalid', function(){
     $(this).addClass('error');
  }).blur(function(){
     // If valid, turn off error
     // If invalid, turn on error
     $(this).toggleClass('error', !this.checkValidity());
  });
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsbin.com/ozesu) of the second version that will work in Chrome and possibly a current/beta version of Opera.

Comment: Doug i am honored to get a response from you! Thanks so much for the reply, it's very useful and thorough!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file is **not** setting "background-color".  It's setting "*background-color". That's probably some sort if IE hack, but you need to set the "real" style property ("background-color", with no asterisk).

Comment: doing `$('input[type=text]').addClass('error')` from chrome's javascript console colors the inputs correctly.

Comment: no unfortunately that was added later to support IE7's special select. As i said the border color is NOT getting supplied.